# How to use the type of an object's property in flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How do you use the type of an object's property in flow? e.g.

```
type A = {
  someproperty: string
}

// throws error
const b: A.someproperty = "hello"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$PropertyType<T,x>` [utility type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-propertytype).

```
type A = {
  someproperty: string
}

// this works fine
const b: $PropertyType<A, 'someproperty'> = "hello"
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have already said in your self-answer, you can use `$PropertyType`. But bear in mind that this is not official and may not always work the same in the future. It could even be removed altogether. React uses `$PropertyType` behind the scenes, but developers at Facebook have the luxury of working together with the Flow team, and have better visibility on the feature roadmap.

If you have control of all the types, you are better off designing them in such a way that you can refer to the property's type by name. In a lot of cases, a simple type alias will work:

```
type SomePropertyOfA = string;
type A = {
  someproperty: SomePropertyOfA
}

const b: SomePropertyOfA = "hello"
```